# posting code in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am saving code in MySQL using php pdo, but the code is not working. my code is...

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$question=$_POST['question'];
$answer=$_POST['desc'];
$query = $conn->prepare("insert into qa(ISSUE,DESC)values(':issue','desc')");
$query->bindParam(':issue',$question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':desc', $answer, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();

if(!$query)
{
    $_SESSION['error']='Error in Posting Issue';
    header('location:index.php');

}
```

but it will not insert the code in MySQL and also it it the data in MySQL like..

:issue!

desc

but whe I use this query...

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$question=$_POST['question'];
$answer=$_POST['desc'];
$conn->exec("INSERT INTO qa (ISSUE,DESC) VALUES ('".$question."','".$answer."')");
if($conn)
{
    $_SESSION['sucess']='Issue Posted Successfully';
    header('location:index.php');

}
else
{
    $_SESSION['error']='Error in Posting Issue';
    header('location:index.php');

}

?>
else

{
    $_SESSION['sucess']='Issue Posted Successfully';
    header('location:index.php');

}
?>
```

Then it will only insert plane text, if I write  then it will not insert anything into database, but the success  session call.

What I want:  **I want that if I enter any type of data either php code or html or css, it will save to data base.**

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Remove `'` from your placeholders - `values(:issue, :desc)` And read manuals carefully if you don't

Comment: `if(!$query)`, typo mistake here

Comment: You don't quote the placeholders. Also second placeholder is missing colon.

Comment: sorry @u_mulder  my mistake, that's why I remove my comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code as @u_mulder said..

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$question=$_POST['question'];
$answer=$_POST['desc'];
$query = $conn->prepare("insert into qa(ISSUE, DESC) values (:issue, :desc)");
$query->bindParam(':issue', $question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':desc', $answer, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();

if(!$query)
{
    $_SESSION['error']='Error in Posting Issue';
    header('location:index.php');

}
```

it will solve the issue..